# Is it possible to change a field behaviour depending on other field value?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have two fields, the first is a boolean and the second is a joinbyarray. What I want to do is to change the withType value of the joinbyarray depending on the boolean value.

I know that I can show different fields depending on the boolean field value but it would be interesting to show the same field changing their options.

Is it possible actually? How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Changing a schema after app start is currently not possible, and there isn't any sort of provision for a smart or dynamic join.

It sounds like you want the editor to make a firm choice so it might not be relevant, but you can define a single join to include multiple piece types in its joining.

> Beginning with Apostrophe 2.58.0, you may also set withType to an
>   array of type names. When you do so, the chooser allows you to pick
>   items of several types via a tabbed interface and create a combined
>   list. These "polymorphic joins" are primarily intended for navigation
>   widgets. They currently do not support pieces filters or
>   joinByArrayReverse.

https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide#joinbyarray

Comment: I know that I can define a multiple piece type join, but that's not the solution that I was looking for, because what I want is to change the types array join depending on the boolean choice.
Anyway, I can solve it with two different fields as I though before.